# Qt QNetworkAccessManager abort authentication

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

In Qt, for `QNetworkAccessManager` we know that `authenticationRequired()` is called when the server returns HTTP 401 code.

Suppose the credentials are inputed by user and the password is incorrect. How do I detect if the password is wrong and cancel the request in this case?

Beside, SDK says

> `QNetworkAccessManager` will cache the credentials internally and will send the same values if the server requires authentication again, without emitting the `authenticationRequired()` signal.

That means if the password is wrong then process is looped forever !!!

Am i missing something?

Thank you in advance

Hai

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole paragraph, it spefically says

> If it rejects the credentials, this signal will be emitted again.

So this is a non-issue.

Comment: If it rejects the credentials, this signal will be emitted again. Then the authenticationRequire slot will send the wrong password again (because it does not aware if the signal is sent the first or the second time). It will loop forever